# Distance between the mouse pointer and the drawing function in OpenLayers in Windowns Browser and Ubuntu browser

Tags: openlayers, windows

I have a strange problem. A distance is created between the mouse pointer and the drawing function on the map.
The picture below is when I use the Firefox browser in Ubuntu and everything is OK (I apologize for the quality of the photos, because when I was taking a screenshot, the mouse pointer disappeared and I had to take a photo with my phone.).
[image]

The picture below is when I use the Firefox browser in Windows, and as you can see, there is a gap between the mouse pointer and the drawing function.
[image]

The code below is where I add the draw function to the map.

```
let draw;

const addPolygonDraw = () => {
    const drawType = "Polygon";
    const activeTip = 'برای ادامه رسم چند ضلعی کلیک کنید'
    const idleTip = 'برای شروع رسم چند ضلعی کلیک کنید';
    let tip = idleTip;
    draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
      source: vectorSource,
      type: drawType,
      style: function (feature) {
        return styleFunction(feature, showSegments.checked, drawType, tip);
      },
    });
    draw.on('drawstart', function () {
      if (clearPrevious.checked) {
        vectorSource.clear();
      }
      modify.setActive(false);
      tip = activeTip;
    });
    draw.on('drawend', function () {
      modifyStyle.setGeometry(tipPoint);
      modify.setActive(true);
      map.once('pointermove', function () {
        modifyStyle.setGeometry();
      });
      tip = idleTip;
    });
    modify.setActive(true);
    // map.addInteraction(draw); }    addPolygonDraw();
```

styles code:

```
const style = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)',
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: '#15283c',
      lineDash: [10, 10],
      width: 3,
    }),
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 5,
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#15283c',
        width: 1
      }),
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: '#02f850',
      }),
    }), });

const labelStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    text: new ol.style.Text({
      font: '14px Calibri,sans-serif',
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
      }),
      backgroundFill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',
      }),
      padding: [3, 3, 3, 3],
      textBaseline: 'bottom',
      // offsetY: -15,
    }),
    image: new ol.style.RegularShape({
      radius: 8,
      points: 3,
      angle: Math.PI,
      displacement: [0, 10],
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',
      }),
    }), });    const tipStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    text: new ol.style.Text({
        font: '13px Calibri,sans-serif',
        // font: '20px' + BYekan_font,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
        }),
        backgroundFill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)',
        }),
        padding: [2, 2, 2, 2],
        textAlign: 'left',
        offsetX: 15,
    }), });    const modifyStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 5,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            // color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',
            color: '#15283c',
            width: 1
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#ff5722',
        }),
    }),
    text: new ol.style.Text({
        text: 'برای اصلاح بکشید',
        font: '13px Calibri,sans-serif',
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
        }),
        backgroundFill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)',
        }),
        padding: [2, 2, 2, 2],
        textAlign: 'left',
        offsetX: 15,
    }), });

const segmentStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    text: new ol.style.Text({
      font: '13px Calibri,sans-serif',
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: '#fff',
      }),
      backgroundFill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',
      }),
      padding: [2, 2, 2, 2],
      textBaseline: 'bottom',
      // offsetY: -12,
    }),
    image: new ol.style.RegularShape({
      radius: 6,
      points: 3,
      angle: Math.PI,
      displacement: [0, 8],
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',
      }),
    }), });

const segmentStyles = [segmentStyle];


const formatLength = (line) => {
    const length = ol.sphere.getLength(line);
    let output;
    if (length > 100) {
      output = Math.round((length / 1000) * 100) / 100 + ' km';
    } else {
      output = Math.round(length * 100) / 100 + ' m';
    }
    return output; };    const formatArea = (polygon) => {
    const area = ol.sphere.getArea(polygon);
    let output;
    if (area > 10000) {
      output = Math.round((area / 1000000) * 100) / 100 + ' km\xB2';
    } else {
      output = Math.round(area * 100) / 100 + ' m\xB2';
    }
    return output; };

const styleFunction = (feature, segments, drawType, tip) => {
    const styles = [style];
    const geometry = feature.getGeometry();
    const type = geometry.getType();
    let point, label, line;
    if (!drawType || drawType === type) {
      if (type === 'Polygon') {
        point = geometry.getInteriorPoint();
        label = formatArea(geometry);
        line = new ol.geom.LineString(geometry.getCoordinates()[0]);
      } else if (type === 'LineString') {
        point = new ol.geom.Point(geometry.getLastCoordinate());
        label = formatLength(geometry);
        line = geometry;
      }
    }
    if (segments && line) {
      let count = 0;
      line.forEachSegment(function (a, b) {
        const segment = new ol.geom.LineString([a, b]);
        const label = formatLength(segment);
        if (segmentStyles.length - 1 < count) {
          segmentStyles.push(segmentStyle.clone());
        }
        const segmentPoint = new ol.geom.Point(segment.getCoordinateAt(0.5));
        segmentStyles[count].setGeometry(segmentPoint);
        segmentStyles[count].getText().setText(label);
        styles.push(segmentStyles[count]);
        count++;
      });
    }
    if (label) {
      labelStyle.setGeometry(point);
      labelStyle.getText().setText(label);
      styles.push(labelStyle);
    }
    if (
        tip &&
        type === 'Point' &&
        !modify.getOverlay().getSource().getFeatures().length
    ) {
        tipPoint = geometry;
        tipStyle.getText().setText(tip);
        styles.push(tipStyle);
    }
    return styles; }
```

Comment: Does the OpenLayers example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure-style.html have the same problem when run directly on the two systems?

Comment: No, this example works correctly. I checked my code several times, but I didn't understand where the problem was!

Comment: I also have another problem that I don't know if it is related to the previous problem or not. All map objects (polygons, markers, etc.) move when zoom in in and zoom out (again, like the first problem, everything is OK in the Ubuntu browser, but these problems occur in the Windows browser). I put all styles code.

Comment: Do you have any css which might be causing the problem?  See https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/13283

Comment: CSS code for map div? I Just set map div height and width to 100%. Even if the problem is because of css codes, why does this only happen in windows browsers and everything is fine in ubuntu browsers?

Comment: If the map div inside another div the css for that might be the problem.

Comment: No, there is no problem with the CSS codes. I think the problem is  due to the anchor feature, because when I move the mouse cursor to the top left of the map, this problem disappears. On the other hand, why did this only happen in the Windows browser? I am confused!